# GWT/GAE - excluding .symbolMap resource files

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I'm using GWT + AppEngine in java and I'm trying to make the deployment process exclude some files from the ones uploaded on the server. Specifically the .symbolMap files  generated by the GWT (because the amount of space taken is too large).
I fount this post: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-web-toolkit/Py-D0oV68fg 
that explains how to exclude them, but it does't work (the version deployed occupies the same amount of space).
I tried all of these lines in my appengine-web.xml files:

```
<exclude path="WEB-INF/deploy/ebas/symbolMaps/**.symbolMap" />
<exclude path="/WEB-INF/deploy/ebas/symbolMaps/**.symbolMap" />
<exclude path="WEB-INF/deploy/ebas/symbolMaps/**.*" />
<exclude path="/WEB-INF/deploy/ebas/symbolMaps/**.*" />
<exclude path="WEB-INF/deploy/ebas/symbolMaps/**.symbolMap" />
<exclude path="/WEB-INF/deploy/ebas/symbolMaps/*" />
```

but it seams this isn't  a solution.
Is there a(another) way to tell the app engine deployment script to exclude those files?

Comment: Are you deploying with the google eclipse plugin, or by a script?

Comment: I'm using Google Eclipse Plugin...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.symbolMap files are created only when adding the -extra compiler argument, so you can just remove it when you compile to deploy.

[check out the official documentation here, if you want to read more about it.](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WebModeExceptions#Resymbolization_/_Deobfuscation)

Comment: Thx for your answer. Using Google Plugin for Eclipse meant that the .simbolMap files were created by default. I found a way to generate them outside the war folder by passing "-deploy [other_folder]" to the GWT compiler

Comment: I would prmote your comment to a bonefide answer (if I could) "I found a way to generate them outside the war folder by passing "faceb [other_folder]" to the GWT compiler"