# Appengine application's deployment takes too long?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I tried to deploy my appengine application on eclipse to server (via ADSL from Japan), after about 40 minutes uploading, it failed with an error:    com.google.appengine.tools.admin.OAuth2ServerConnection$OAuthInvalidTokenException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/rollback?app_id=XXXXX&version=1&
401 Unauthorized
Invalid OAuth token

My questions are:

1) My project folder's stuff amounts to about 500MB now. Is it too big size?

2) If there is another project referenced by my project on the Build Path, does deploying tool also upload whole of it?

3) I tried to cancel deploying process. After 10 minutes later, "User cancelled" message emerged on the console. But the process continues after then for long time. Cancellation of deployment is forbidden?

4) What is the error message saying?

I appreciate any advice. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

500MB for a the source of your project is way too big and of course it will take some time to deploy. Are you sure you need all these files?

I'm suspecting that you're uploading lots of static files that I'm guessing could (should) be treated differently.

If you want to exclude some files from being deployed on Google App Engine, refere to the docs  in [Java Application Configuration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Including_and_Excluding_Files).

Comment: Thanks for reply. My poject uses GWT which seems to generate a lot of files.Can I exclude output of GWT compiler?

Comment: Sorry, I found related post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591915/gwt-gae-excluding-symbolmap-resource-files) about excluding symbolmap files.

Comment: @user1639968 I updated my answer with a link.. this is what you should do instead.. just ignore the folders that are not useful on production.. all the source code of GWT to begin with...

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest App engine SDK.
I upgraded from 1.7.0 to 1.7.7 and my deployment went down from 10+ mins to a few seconds!
(my proj is around 230MB)

I face the same issue with cancellation. I find it easier and faster to let it complete deployment and then re-deploy, rather than wait for it to cancel.